# MenuItemCollection vs. List<MenuItem>

Tags: c#, lambda, extension-methods, menuitem

Recently I wrote a piece of C# code utilizing a Lambda expression:

```
var dynMenu = new List<MenuItem>();
// some code to add menu items to dynMenu
if (!dynMenu.Any(x => x.Text == controller))
{ 
    // do something
}
```

While going thru my code, I discovered that each MenuItem itself has a property called ChildItems which happens to be of type MenuItemCollection. Intrigued, I figured I would replace my List of MenuItem with this MenuItemCollection.

Upon changing the first line to:

```
var dynMenu = new MenuItemCollection();
```

I noticed that this MenuItemCollection type has no Extension Methods like "Any<>", "All<>", "First<>", etc., etc. -- which I find strange.

Is there a way to utilize Lambda expressions here?

Should I just go back to using "List<<\MenuItem>"?

Comment: use the AsQueryable extension method of OfType<MenuItem>() extension method and it'll give you access to all the linq goodness.

Comment: @Darren, should make that an answer.

Comment: Do you mean like this?  dynMenu.AsQueryable().OfType<MenuItem>().Any(x => x.Text == "something");

Comment: Using Cast<T> is more appropriate than OfType<T> here.  OfType actually filters the collection - in this case, you know, in advance, that the type of every element is the same, so Cast<T> is better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[MenuItemCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menu.menuitemcollection.aspx) is a .NET 1.1 class.  It does not implement any of the generic collection interfaces, in particular, `IEnumerable<MenuItem>`.

Since this only implements IEnumerable and not `IEnumerable<MenuItem>`, all of the extension methods LINQ provides which require this don't work.  However, you can get them back by doing:

```
if (dynMenu.Cast<MenuItem>().Any(x => x.Test == controller)) { // ...
```

The [Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) extension method converts the `IEnumerable` to `IEnumerable<T>`, providing access to the other LINQ extension methods.

Comment: A ha. I hadn't realized that is was .NET 1.1 -- So should I not be using it? I'm basically trying to build a dynamically-constructed multi-nested navigation-bar in ASP.NET MVC and it seemed like a reasonable structure to use. (rather than invent my own...)

Comment: @Pretzel: It depends - I'd probably just use List<T> instead.  If, however, you're going to have to create a MenuItemCollection eventually, sometimes it's easier to just use it up front (rare, though).

Comment: Hmmm... ok. I'll think about it.  Thanks for the advice and the IEnumerable / Type lesson!

Answer (score 1):

MenuItemCollection is a specialized collection and does not implement the IEnumerable Interface to use the Linq Extension Methods that you name above.  I would just go back to the generic list as it has more functionality

Comment: It does implement IEnumerable, just not IEnumerable<T>.